# how to solve linkedlist interview questions when interviewer ask us to do

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

In Interviews If interviewers ask us to implement linkedlist problems we have to write our own linked lists or we can just use predefined classed in java/c# ?

Comment: Depends on what the interviewer wants. Note that this question is offtopic here. If you have similar questions or want to reask yours in a more appropriate place, consider using http://workplace.stackexchange.com

Comment: You should ask your interviewer.

Answer (score 1):

Odds are, he/she wants to know that you are skilled enough to be able to write your own.

And you should be able to answer this easily.  Study up.